# Best way to build a database of php errors using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, error-handling, pdo

I'm building a newsletter CMS and I want to loog any errors to a database with information like timestamp, error, userID and function info. What's the best way to do this?

I'm thinking I should build a class that handles the errors and inputs them into a MYsql table using PDO.

pseudo code:

```
    class sbmtErr
{
   private $errStrng;

   protected function sndErr($err, $usrData, $mthd){

      $sndErrPDO = new myPDO;

      $this->errStrng = "INSERT INTO errTbl (error, userID, method) VALUES ('".$err."', ".usrData['usrID'].", '".$mthd."')";

      $sndErrPDO->sqlQry($errStrng);
   }
}
```

My problem here is I don't know how to isolate the method that threw the error.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you log the error if something with the database fails? ;)

Comment: Have a look at [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Comment: I don't get people using these names!  SubmitError, $errorString, $sendErrorPDO. Why the silly shorthands?

Comment: @Truth If I were to not use self describing names then what should I use? Random numbers and letters would be too confusing. In small programs using variable like $i are more than adequate. If you are working on a bigger program with hundreds of variables it would become very confusting very fast. What do you use when you code?

Comment: @Gumbo good point. That's why it's pseudo code.

Comment: You misunderstand the point that @truth is trying to make. Why use a "silly shorthand" like sbmtErr or $sndErrPDO when you could use submitError or $sendErrorPDO which are much clearer and descriptive. I imagine that's what he uses when he codes.

Comment: Ahhh... @vascowhite I see. Then I do it just because I don't like vowels. :)

Comment: Except for 'e'? You seen to be ok with that :)

Comment: @vascowhite It's the most commonly used letter in the english language. Hard to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the exception class. `CMSErrorException` , when thrown (i.e. On construct) use reflection to find out things like function, line number, etc. how you find the user's id depends on how you keep it.

Then, regardless of what you do when you catch it, you call a method (again from the construct) which logs it into the database.

Careful not to throw these custom exceptions inside of the exception code, as it might cause an infinite loop in case of a database error.

Comment: Sweet, I'mm trying this out tonight.